# JPA @Inheritance strategy failure after domain deported to a JAR

Tags: jpa, testing, spring-data-jpa

I had to change a JPA Inheritance strategy from SINGLE_TABLE to JOINED after moving my entities to an Maven module, in order for them to used from different applications.
The junit tests were OK when launched within Eclipse (Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA) but failed at Maven build (Mapping Exception).

```
@Entity
//@Inheritance(strategy = TABLE_PER_CLASS)
//@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "privilege_datarealm_type")
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
public abstract class PrivilegeDataRealm<E extends SchemaElement>
    extends Privilege<PrivilegeDataRealm<E>>
    implements SchemaElement {
```

Does anyone have any clue of explanations for this issue ?

Comment: I wonder what the "MappingException" is ... or indeed where that exception comes from (because it isnt a JPA exception)

Comment: Can you post some stack trace or log ?

Comment: This is the trace I kept : MappingException "cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping"
Unfortunatly I didn't keep the exception package; it can come from hibernate of spring framework.